# Upgraded to Rails 3.2.0 and get SSLError with Devise & tlsmail gem for Google Apps?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I just upgraded to Rails 3.2.0 and get this error after signing up to send a welcome email:

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create

SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server..... 
certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

I am using these gems (most relevant ones):

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.0'
gem "pg", "0.12.0"
gem "devise", "1.5.3"
gem "thin", "1.3.1"
gem "eventmachine", "1.0.0.beta.4.1" # I'm on Windows 7 64x
gem "tlsmail", "0.0.1"
```

Then to get Google Apps and mailing working:

environments/development.rb

```
require 'tlsmail'
  Net::SMTP.enable_tls(OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE)
  ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.perform_deliveries = true
  ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :enable_starttls_auto => true,
    :address            => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    :port               => 587,
    :tls                => true,
    :domain             => 'app.com',
    :authentication     => :plain,
    :user_name          => 'test@myapp.com',
    :password           => 'app'
  }

config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
```

I'm not using any type of SSL/HTTPS right now.

Anyone else have this issue or know how to fix it?

**UPDATE September 01, 2012**

You don't need this gem anymore as gmail works with Rails now.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there are some bugs in rails 3.2. I've been told it's advisable to hold off upgrading to 3.2 until they work out some of the kinks by some fellow developers. Not certain but one of these bugs could be affecting you here.

Comment: I'm still on `3.0.11`.  Still need to upgrade to `3.1.x` at some point but I've been holding off until I have some time to digest the changes : ).  As Michael Hartl says in his [RoR tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-3-1#top): 'This is the price we pay for being on the bleeding edge—sometimes we get cut.'

Answer (score 10):

Apparently the `:tls => true` option for `ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings` doesn't work in Rails 3.2. Try removing it so that you're left with:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address            => 'smtp.gmail.com',
  :port               => 587,
  :domain             => 'app.com',
  :authentication     => :plain,
  :user_name          => 'test@myapp.com',
  :password           => 'app'
}
```

I was having the same issue and this worked for me. I haven't found any official documentation on it yet; was searching around and [Dan Connor's blog post](http://danconnor.com/post/4f65ea41daac4ed03100003a/actionmailer_3_2_0_upgrade_ssl_issue) tipped me off.